# Problema en Maven en Netbeans

Tags: java, maven

Estoy probando por primera vez Maven en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans), creando un nuevo Java Proyect en Maven, creandome toda la estructura sin problemas, incluso el `pom.xml`.
Ahora, dentro de Source Packages simplemente cree una clase java con un `System.Out.Println("hola")` y al ejecutar me sale esto:
Alquien sabe que debo hacer? Es la primera vez que trabajo con Maven! 
Gracias!!!

Mi pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gonzalo.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenGestionAeropuertos</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

El error:

```
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.100s
Finished at: Tue May 05 21:11:07 ART 2020
Final Memory: 6M/121M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Pero tengo que instalar Maven en mi sistema operativo?

Comment: Maven vinene como parte de tu instalaión de netbeans aunque no lo hayas instalado manualkmente, es por eso que puedes correr un proyecto maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentan, es dificil saber el problema si no posteas completo el pom, pero el error que te esta saliendo basicamente es porque estas usando el repo central de maven con http en lugar de hacerlo con http**s**, tal vez en tu pom tienes configurado el repositorio de esa forma, basta con que lo definas con https. Trata de ingresar a estas URLS:

- http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1 -> Error 501 (HTTPS Required)
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/ -> OK

Por otro lado, puedes usar la version de maven que ya trae NetBeans o instalarlo en tu pc, en lo presonal prefiero la segunda opcion.

Comment: Hola! La verdad soy nuevo en Maven. Ahi puse mi pom, para que puedas verlo.

Comment: Pero ese link https, donde lo deberia incrustar?

Comment: Incluso, cuando trato de ejecutar dentro de mi carpeta Source Packages un .java ni siquiera me permite ejecutarlo, porque sera?

Answer (score 0):

Puede deberse a dos cosas:

- Que generalmente el maven embebido de netbeans viene en una verisón relativamente vieja.

Si es el caso, ee debería de ver al inicio de tu traza la versión, generalmente es recomendable hacer una [instalación local de maven](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-on-windows/).

- una definición por defecto del repositorio maven central.

```
  <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>maven central</id>
              <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
          </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Como verás aquí toca cambiar [conforme reportan en su página oficial](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required) el repo de http a https.

- Que al no especificar versiones de los plugins que usa por defecto use versiones muy viejas de los plugins

Si bien para la mayoría de los proyectos no es necesario, si tu JDK fuera mayor a Java 8, lo más sensato sería poner explícitamente la configuración para los plugins: [maven-compiler-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-compiler-plugin), [maven-exec-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-exec-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Cree un proyecto nuevo en NetBeans con Maven y no podía compilarlo,
or one of its dependencies could not be resolved SOLVED

Resulta que por defecto NetBeans estaba apuntando al repositorio central de Maven que utilizaba http y que ahora ya no esta en funcionamiento, el nuevo repositorio tiene mayor seguridad por eso utiliza https:

Este vídeo me ayudo a reparar el error y ahora mi proyecto ya compila:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRGQBU9gy2Q

Agregue este código a un archivo settings.xml justo por debajo de la etiqueta "mirrors"

----Código agregado

```
 <mirror>
 <id>mirror1</id>
 <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
 <name>mirror1</name>
 <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
 </mirror>
```

---

Este archivo lo encontré en la ruta \Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\conf\settings.xml

Después de modificar este archivo hice un clean and build sobre mi proyecto Maven y compilo satisfactoriamente.