# por qué me aparece este error traté de solucionarlo con \m2\setting.xml pero no encuentro nada

Tags: java, maven

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Realizaba una GUI y esto me señaló

> Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer
> artifact org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1 from/to central
> (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
> read the following articles: [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

Borré la carpeta 1.2.1 para que se vuelva a descargar y nada.

Comment: puedes poner tu pom? por cierto te dice en el error: HTTPS Required así que yo creo que tu maven central o algunos de tus repos está con http en vez de https

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema en Maven en Netbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352702/problema-en-maven-en-netbeans)

Comment: no sé si sea la imagen que compartí

Comment: Efectivamente, ese es tu pom. Puedes poner tu setting.xml que dices que modificaste? Especialmente la parte donde dice repositories

Comment: en eso no le modifique nada

Comment: entonces no lo tenías el archivo?

Comment: el xml si, solo falla al ejecutar eso pero ya entendi el problema pero no sé donde cambiar este enlace http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom y agregarle una "s" al http

Comment: pues en ese caso la solución es la misma de la pregunta que te puse